# Flask application with Blueprints+uWSGI+nginx returning 404's (no routing?)

Tags: nginx, flask, url-routing, uwsgi

Having successfully deployed a minimal Flask app with nginx+uWSGI, I am stumped by this.

```
from flask import Flask
from bsfdash.users import users
from bsfdash.dashboard import dashboard 
from bsfdash.customs import customs
from bsfdash import app 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(dashboard)
    app.register_blueprint(customs)

    app.run()
```

To confirm my nginx and uWSGI settings are correct, I tested with a simple "Hello World" Flask application with @app.route('/') that returns "Hi!" - It worked as expected.

However, The app shown above works as expected using the flask web-server on localhost:5000 - but does not route @dashboard.route('/') blueprint when called via uWSGI.

I have found zero information about deploying modular Flask applications containing Blueprints with uWSGI.

Why does this application work as a Flask web-server but is braindead through uWSGI?

Comment: But when `uwsgi` imports `app`, it doesn't run the `__main__` block; move your blueprint registrations either. Move those *out* of the `if` test.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters Moved the blueprint registrations out of the if test and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us more information about your app structure ?
I have a working Flask app with Blueprints that looks like, if it can help you.

App/run.py :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/subone")

from iel import app, manager
from flask.ext.migrate import MigrateCommand

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

app.debug = True
manager.run()
```

App/subone/**__init__**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from subone import models

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('settings')

manager = Manager(app)

#Blueprints
from catalog.views import catalog
app.register_blueprint(catalog)

from login.views import login
app.register_blueprint(login,url_prefix="/login")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

App/subone/catalog/**__init__**.py :

```
from flask import Blueprint
```